# In a HTML helper dropdownlist, how to get foreign key data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET. My form look like this

[image]

This code display role in Form

```
  @Html.DropDownList("id", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.lis, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

in Controller

```
  public ActionResult register()
    {      // 
        ViewBag.lis = new SelectList(new dbdemoEntities().Roles, "id", "name");
        return View();
    }
```

ROLE CLASS

```
  public partial class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual Register Register { get; set; }
}
```

Register class

```
   public partial class Register
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> phone_no { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that I can get all data except for Role. The role is null. How do I get the Role ID?

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult register(Register obj)
    {
        using(var db = new dbdemoEntities())
        {
            var data = new Register()
            {

                email = obj.email,
                name = obj.name,
                password = obj.password,
                phone_no = obj.phone_no,
                Role = obj.Role
            };

            db.Registers.Add(data);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.register = "Your account has been registered!";
        }

        return PartialView();
    }
```

I think the problem is that I should write model => model.role like the example of the name here.

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

here is what I updated now

```
    ViewBag.lis = new SelectList(new dbdemoEntities().Roles, "Id", "name");
```

In HTML

[image]

Problem after update:

[image]

After changing

```
      Role = db.Roles.Single(r => r.Id == obj.Role.Id)
```

Here is another error

[image]

Comment: In your Register class Id is Role Id or a separate property?

Comment: I update the question.. 
I didn't get your meaning?

Comment: You mean your Id property is not setting up?

Comment: Yes In Register. foreign key id(role) is not setting up..

Comment: "don't have time to study. need answer asap", hmm... good luck with that approach! `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Change: `ViewBag.lis = new SelectList(new dbdemoEntities().Roles, "id", "name");`

to

```
 ViewBag.lis = new SelectList(new dbdemoEntities().Roles, "Id", "name");
```

and then:

```
@Html.DropDownList(model => model.Role.Id, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.lis, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

and also make a constructor for **Register** class:

```
public partial class Register
{
    public Register()
    {
        this.Role = new Role();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> phone_no { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

====== **Update** =======

Change the action like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult register(Register obj)
    {
        using(var db = new dbdemoEntities())
        {
            var data = new Register()
            {
                email = obj.email,
                name = obj.name,
                password = obj.password,
                phone_no = obj.phone_no,
                Role = db.Roles.Single(r=> r.Id == obj.Role.Id)
            };

            db.Registers.Add(data);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.register = "Your account has been registered!";
        }

        return PartialView();
    }
```

Comment: It didn't work.. I did add constructor now..
I Updated the question.. Look at last three things
name = null the highlighted row in Picture

Comment: you need just Id, I'll update my answer. follow that.

Comment: did you see that?

Comment: in data.
id was okay.
now Name is also okay that worked but got another problem..
new row Entity wrapper is showing up now 
Uploading picture in question

Comment: No, look at last picture

Comment: Is your context **LazyLoadingEnabled** and **ProxyCreationEnabled** on?

Comment: you don't need these in Asp.Net app, disable these. Do you know how?

Comment: I just made the improvement I think that problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

Change to this this if you want to post Register.Id property:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id,(SelectList) ViewBag.list,new { @class="form-control"})
```

Comment: didn't work.
I even tried to change it to model.role

Comment: That's how I am getting data from database table "Role"  in Action



 ViewBag.lis = new SelectList(new dbdemoEntities().Roles, "id", "name");
           
in HTML I want that when an item in select it should be stored in Model.Role   // which is a foreign key

   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Role, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.lis,  new { @class = "form-control" })

Comment: You mean Register.Id isn't setting up? You can't post complete Role object from Dropdownlist because it can set only one selected property. If you want to set `Register.Role.Id` change to `model=>mode.Role.Id`